# popover from an arbitrary anchor point - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I would like to make a popover from a button like this pic:

[image]

to do this I'm following below steps:

1.I created a view controller(plus a Controller) and I changed size it to 100*200

2.I make a segue from first controller (`JobsViewController`) to above controller as `present as popover` and I set a identifier:

[image]

3.in `JobsViewController`:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showFeatureJobs" {

        //let popoverViewController = segue.destination
        // popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        // popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self

        // get a reference to the view controller for the popover
        let popController = UIStoryboard(name: "JobsViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showFeatureJobs")

        // set the presentation style
        popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

        // set up the popover presentation controller
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as! UIView? // button
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = (sender?.bounds)!

        // present the popover
        self.present(popController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}

// MARK: - UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {

    // Force popover style
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

4.but when I click on my button, my popover cover all my page:

[image]

where is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The popover controller should already be instantiated by the storyboard seque.  You need to use the one that's already there (and properly sized) instead of creating a new one.

Something like :

```
  if let popOver = segue?.destination.popoverPresentationController,
  { popOver.sourceRect = yourAnchor.bounds }
```

I'm unsure how you got the sender parameter of type AnyObject? to have a .bounds property to use as the sourceRect so I have to assume that you got some appropriate coordinates for your dynamic anchor location somewhere else in the actual running code.

Answer (score 0):

Same situation occurred with me. it's not being call proper delegate. you should call delegate function in proper language like swift(3.0, 4.0). Hope it will help you

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SYwm.png)

Answer (score 0):

in your prepareForSegue func you can change your sender for AnyObject to UIBarButtonItem and then put the line of code before you present the popover

```
 if let popoverController = popController.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.barButtonItem = sender 
     }
```

if you still wanna use Anyobject then you will have to cast it as UIBarButtonItem

```
    if let popoverController = popController.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.barButtonItem = sender as? UIBarButtonItem
     }
```

i hope this works for you